# tikzmath: strange replacement

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I don't know why, but I tried to print some code in a `tikzmath` file, and the result is really strange, it looks like that `tikzmath` tries to substitute texts even if does not begin with a backslash... For example here the variable is not even used, and a substitution is done...

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    % Fails
    \color = "blue!80";
    % Works
    % \ccolor = "blue!80";
    {\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1,1) node{$\textcolor{red}{A}$};};
  }      
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

Wanted output: [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Try `node[red]{$A$};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your statement `\color = "blue!80";` overrides the TeX command `\color`. If you comment out this line, it also works as expected. Otherwise you can use `{\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (1,1) node[red]{$A$};};`, but I'd recommend not to (ab)use TeX commands like this.

Comment: Hum I'm so stupid. Thank you! And I don't want to use `node[red]` here because in "real life" I just want to change a single letter. Thank you!